# Not java based editor for Ruby on Rails on windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, editor

It appears that NetBeans and Aptana/RadRails are the most common adopted IDE's for Ruby on Rails development, but both needs the Java Runtime Environment to run.

I'm looking for an IDE wich doesn't need JRE to run. If it is lightweight and installs very fast would be better, because I will be programming in computers with old hardware and Windows XP.

Do you know any? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not use a java IDE? The ruby/rails version of Netbeans is tiny (only 59 megs), quick and full featured.

Comment: See here for more IDEs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826164/what-is-the-best-ruby-on-rails-ide/855716

Comment: Java will run very slowly in the intended pc's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [E](http://e-texteditor.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) and the [command line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html).

Comment: I use that for smaller projects, for bigger ones I tend to use Netbeans

Answer (score 1):

[Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) is one of the best IDEs I've ever used, and it has Rails support (although maybe not as good as Aptana/RadRails). If you have money to spare, I'd highly recommend Komodo IDE, as it has some great extra features, but if not, Komodo Edit has everything you need. As for speed, it's slow to start up but after that it's as fast as any other "lightweight" editor you've used.

Comment: Yeah, the RX Toolkit is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I would say that Vim paired with [rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) is amongst the most popular editors for Rails. Vim, gVim and Cream are all available for Windows.

Learning curve is massively steep, but its worth it.

Also, if you are doing any serious Rails work, development on Windows sucks. It takes way too long to spin up a script/console or a web. Tooling is much better on Linux. When I'm doing Rails work on my Windows box I do it on an Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 0):

What about the editor that comes with ruby-one-click for windows? Would it work? (the one written in ruby).

There is also gvim or vim if you are feeling adventurous.

Answer (score -1):

[JetBrains RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html)

I did not use this program, but "[System Requirements](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/index.html#win)" did not indicate requirements for Java Runtime Environment in Windows version.

Comment: Requires java, doesn't list it.